# Вытащить строку между определёнными символами javascript

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуйте.

Объясните мне, почему этот код ниже:

```
'tag#id.class@attr'.match(/\.|\@|\#(.+?)\.|\@|\#?^/gi)
```

выводит всегда:

```
["", "#id.", "@"]
```

Когда я рассчитывал получить:

```
["id", "class", "attr"]
```

В чем моя ошибка? Вроде указал, чтоб вытягивалась инфа, которая лежит между:
`\.` или этим `\@` или этим `\#` символами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну что-то типа такого )

```js
$(function() {
  var arr = 'tag#id.class@attr'.match(/[#@.]([^#@.]*)/g);
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    arr[i] = arr[i].replace(/^.(.+)$/, '$1')
  };
  alert(arr)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Работает на 5+ =)
Благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

вот сервис для тестирования регулярных выражений [rubular.com](http://rubular.com/)

Попробуй вот это: `'tag#id.class@attr'.match(/\#(.+?)\.(.+?)\@(.+)/gi)`